# After importing a fbx animation mesh/part is missing. (Unreal Engine)

Tags: animation, export, .fbx, unreal-engine

I downloaded a fbx animation of a hand reloading a weapon. In blender I opened the fbx file and added texture to the hand and weapon. I selected the export fbx option and exported with ‘bake animation’ selected and added a root. Also it had 2 roots so I merged to become one. This affects/breaks the right hand but luckily I only need the left hand + weapon.  When I import this animation to UE4 the weapon is missing, but the hands are working normally. And the animation is splitted into several frames instead of being just one.

I want to export both hands and weapons between a certain range of frames, say frames 50 up to 150 and it supposed to be just one animation inside Unreal Engine and not several like the picture below.

The link where I downloaded the fbx animation
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/sawnoff-animated-806f8327bed34fc3b0e3911d01f0566d

Blender:[image]

Splitted animation in UE and missing weapon:
[image]

Searching the web it seems that the weapon is not attached to the hand skeleton? But I don't understand.